# How to get SHAP values of the model averaged by folds?

Tags: python, machine-learning

This is way I can values from single fold trained model

```
clf.fit(X_train, y_train, 
        eval_set=[(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)], 
        eval_metric='auc', verbose=100, early_stopping_rounds=200)
import shap  # package used to calculate Shap values
# Create object that can calculate shap values
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(clf)
# Calculate Shap values
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test)
```

As you know result from different fold might be different - how to average this shap_values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because we have such rule:

> It is fine to average the SHAP values from models with the same output
>   trained on the same input features, just make sure to also average the
>   expected_value from each explainer. However, if you have
>   non-overlapping test sets then you can't average the SHAP values from
>   the test sets since they are for different samples. You could just
>   explain the SHAP values for the whole dataset using each of your
>   models and then average that into a single matrix. (It's fine to
>   explain examples in your training set, just remember you may be
>   overfit to them)

So we need here some holdout dataset to follow that rule. I did something like this to get erything to work as expected:

```
shap_values = None
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, StratifiedKFold
(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test) = train_test_split(df[feat], df['target'].values, 
                                     test_size=0.2, shuffle  = True,stratify =df['target'].values,
                                     random_state=42) 

folds = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
folds_idx = [(train_idx, val_idx) 
                 for train_idx, val_idx in folds.split(X_train, y=y_train)]
auc_scores = []
oof_preds = np.zeros(df[feat].shape[0])
test_preds = []

for n_fold, (train_idx, valid_idx) in enumerate(folds_idx):
    train_x, train_y = df[feat].iloc[train_idx], df['target'].iloc[train_idx]
    valid_x, valid_y = df[feat].iloc[valid_idx], df['target'].iloc[valid_idx]    
    clf = lgb.LGBMClassifier(nthread=4,            boosting_type= 'gbdt', is_unbalance= True,random_state = 42,
            learning_rate= 0.05, max_depth= 3,
            reg_lambda=0.1 , reg_alpha= 0.01,min_child_samples= 21,subsample_for_bin= 5000,
            metric= 'auc', n_estimators= 5000    )
    clf.fit(train_x, train_y, 
            eval_set=[(train_x, train_y), (valid_x, valid_y)], 
            eval_metric='auc', verbose=False, early_stopping_rounds=100)
    explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(clf)
    if shap_values is None:
        shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)
    else:
        shap_values += explainer.shap_values(X_test)       
    oof_preds[valid_idx] = clf.predict_proba(valid_x)[:, 1]   
    auc_scores.append(roc_auc_score(valid_y, oof_preds[valid_idx]))
print( 'AUC: ', np.mean(auc_scores))
shap_values /= 10 # number of folds
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test)
```